# How to add image in UINavigationBar in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage, uinavigationbar

In my app, i want to add image(logo) in Navigation bar. I am working on XCode 4.2 and iOS 5.

I know `UINavigationBar`, `UIToolBar` has been changed in iOS 5. So iOS 4.2 `UINavigationBar` code won't work in iOS 5.

I want to support display image in `UINavigationBar` in both 4.2 and 5 version.

I want to be display image in `UINavigationBar` like as in below screenshot.

[image: Navigation bar image]

Please help in this regards and if there is any sample code means its very helpful to me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `UINavigationItem.titleView` and `UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`. Like this :

```
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Here I am using `UIImageView` as custom view, but it can be `UIButton` with custom image.

Comment: Will this work for both iOS4 and 5 ? and is it the `clingle` Logo you are trying to add and not the background image for UINavigationbar ?

Comment: It does on Simulator at least. And I don't see any reason it should not. I didn't understand your second question.

Comment: thanks. but I noticed the item object is not released in your example.

Comment: the image view is also leaked here.

Comment: I am using ARC... :) @MartinReichl

Comment: The author stated that the solution should work also in iOS 4, so I did not thought about ARC :)

Comment: You can use ARC for iOS 4 and above, although weak reference is not supported in ios4.

Comment: Just a not, you shouldnt say @"youtimage.png". @"yourimage" will suffice, iOS will figure out the correct image to load.

Comment: is there a way to automatically scale it to fit the navbar?

Answer (score 33):

Another way without using a viewController

```
// Create your image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo.png"];
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

// set the image view to the title view
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageview;
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift version:
You can create a protocol extension for using the function in your view controllers

```
protocol Customizable {
    var navigationItem: UINavigationItem { get }
}

extension Customizable {
    func setNavBarLogo() {

        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")
        let logoImageView = UIImageView(image: logo)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView
    }
}
```