# How can I place two images within a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios

For the navigation controller I have onscreen, I'd like to place two images within the navigation bar. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `UINavigationItem.titleView` and `UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`. Like this :

```
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Here I am using `UIImageView` as custom view, but it can be `UIButton` with custom image.

Check this:
[How to add image in UINavigationBar in IPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814056/how-to-add-image-in-uinavigationbar-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Thank you very much my problem is resolved

Comment: you are always welcome..